# vinkla/Pusher doesn't work with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, pusher

I've been trying to install vinkla/pusher to  my laravel project but it throws me a lot of errors

```
Problem 1
        - Installation request for vinkla/pusher 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by vinkla/pusher[2.1.0].
        - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - vinkla/pusher 2.1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.
    0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
        - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.4.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36].
```

is the package deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this package has been changed to pusher/pusher-http-laravel, for more data : https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-laravel